# FTP Authentication with Public Key?

Tags: ftp

Is it possible to login via ftp to my dedicated server using a private/public key pair? i.e without using a password?

Comment: Yes, using [scp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy) it is possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FTP can use SSL, which supports client authentication using X.509 certificates. However, while many FTP servers support FTPS, I don't know of any which support client certificates. (In addition, client authentication is complicated in SSL – in many cases, you would have to create and maintain your own certificate authority and stuff. Not many *clients* support this kind of authentication, either.)

Much easier is to use SFTP, the SSH file transfer protocol. It uses exactly the same keys as "normal" SSH would. On Windows, [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) and [FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) support SFTP.

Comment: thank you, I know about SFTP. the problem is that is way more slower than normal ftp..

Comment: is there any command line based version of winscp or filezilla is availble ?

Comment: Yes, and it's called `winscp`. For SFTP, you can use `psftp` from PuTTY.